# Running Jetty 9 on Java 6

Tags: java, jetty, java-6, jetty-9

I work for a corporation that won't upgrade from JRE 6 to JRE 7 on our servers. I have successfully developed some code that works on JRE 7 using Jetty 9. However, I can't run this code on the corporation server. I was wondering if anyone out here knew of a way to run Jetty 9 on JRE 6. I specifically need the HTTPConfiguration class from Jetty 9.

The only potential thing I can think of would be to download Jetty, set it to a 1.6 compliance and work from that. I'm really hoping (with a shot in the dark) that someone has a better idea.

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate on the [Jetty users](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/jetty-users) mailing list.

Answer (score 18):

No, Jetty 9 required Java 7 since the servlet api (servlet 3.1) requires Java 7.  While 9.0 could have in theory worked on Java 6 our intent had been that 9 would be servlet 3.1 and it wasn't until 9.1 that we made the servlet api switch...which was mostly due to timing issues more than anything.

[update] Jetty 9.2.x is Java 7 and Jetty 9.3.x onwards will require Java 8.  This is largely due to requirements of supporting the HTTP/2 protocol which Jetty 9.3.x does...in spades.